# includePaths property of @indexedEmbedded does not creating index while put over nested instances field

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

Using below version for hibernate search:

- hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-search-engine-4.4.2.Final.jar
- hibernate-search-analyzers-3.3.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-search-orm-4.4.2.Final.jar
- lucene-core-3.6.2.jar

I am facing problem with `includePaths` property of `@indexedEmbedded` annotations when putting over instances of instance. For example: (assume all fields have proper getter/setter)

Root class:

```
@Indexed
public class RootClass {

@IndexedEmbedded
private Set<Instance> setOfInstances;

}
```

Instance class:

```
public class Instance {

@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, norms = Norms.NO, store = Store.NO)
private String name;

@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, norms = Norms.NO, store = Store.NO)
private String vesion;

@IndexedEmbedded(includePaths={"type", "location", "users.name", "users.country"})
private InstanceDetail deltail;
}
```

InstanceDetail  class:

```
public class InstanceDetail{

@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, norms = Norms.NO, store = Store.NO)
private int type;

@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, norms = Norms.NO, store = Store.NO)
private String location;

@IndexedEmbedded
private Set<User> users;

@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, norms = Norms.NO, store = Store.NO)
private String ref1;

@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, norms = Norms.NO, store = Store.NO)
private String ref2

@IndexedEmbedded
private Set<Area> usersArea;
}
```

User class:

```
public class User{
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, norms = Norms.NO, store = Store.NO)
    private String name;

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, norms = Norms.NO, store = Store.NO)
    private String address;

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, norms = Norms.NO, store = Store.NO)
    private String mobile;

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, norms = Norms.NO, store = Store.NO)
    private String country;
}
```

So when i define **`includePaths`** property of **`IndexedEmbedded`** annotation over `InstanceDetail` of `Instance`, then **NO** field of **`InstanceDetail`** (others are coming like name/vesion) are getting indexed for RootClass object. (Confirm by logs). No any exception are coming.

So this is as per design of HibernateSearch or something worng with my implementations.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but you might run into a bug related to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1112

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to specify a `depth` on the `@IndexedEmedded` annotation on `Instance.deltail` in order to get the properties of `InstanceDetail` to come through.  According to the Javadocs:

> Stop indexing embedded elements when depth is reached depth=1 means
>   the associated element is indexed, but not its embedded elements.
>
> The default value depends on the value of the includePaths attribute:
>   if no paths are defined, the default is Integer.MAX_VALUE; if any
>   includePaths are defined, the default depth is interpreted as 0 if not
>   specified to a different value than it's default.

Setting the `depth` to `1` will embed the properties of `InstanceDetail`, while setting it to `2` will embed both the properties of `InstanceDetail` and its associated `User`s.

Comment: As per hibernate search reference guide 4.4.2:

`When using includePaths, and leaving
depth undefined, behavior is equivalent to setting depth=0: only the included paths are indexed.`

So when we specify path then only those value get indexed .

Comment: If the embedded entity were indexed separately, then the `includePaths` would be placed in the entity's index; however, since the entity is being embedded inside another, when the indexing code is embedding the entity inside the owning entity's index, it hits the `depth=0` default and stops indexing any paths related to the embedded entity.